# Solve the equation: $a \times c = b + c$ for linearly independent vectors a and b.

Tags: vectors

$a$, $b$ and $c$ are all vectors. $a \times c$ is the cross product of $a$ and $c$. After making a quick sketch, I found that $b$, $c$ and $a \times c$ form a right triangle, which I was not sure how to use to come to a solution. I ended up getting that $a=c$ and $c=-b$, but I'm pretty sure that is wrong. Another question is whether the answer also holds true for an arbitrary pair of vectors.

Comment: (1) what are you solving for? You've got three variables and only one equation, so all you can do is solve for one of them in terms of the other two. Which two are known, and which one is unknown? (2) In your "solution", you talk about "$x$", but there is no "$x$" anywhere in the problem. What is $x$?

Comment: My bad, x is meant to be c. I suppose you're supposed to solve for c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $a$ and $b$ are linearly independent, $a\times b$ is non-zero and not a multiple of either. Therefore $\{a, b, a\times b\}$ forms a basis for three dimensional space. So any $c$ must have a unique expression as
$$c = xa + yb + z(a\times b)$$
for some scalars $x,y,z$. Now
$$a\times c = x(a\times a) + y(a\times b) + z(a\times(a\times b)) = z(a\cdot b)a - z\|a\|^2b+y(a \times b)$$
since $a\times a = 0$ and making use of the vector triple product rule. Also, $$b + c = xa + (y+1)b + z(a\times b)$$
Equating these two, and again making use of the uniqueness of representation in a basis, we get
$$x = z(a\cdot b)\\y + 1 = -z\|a\|^2\\z = y$$
Which solves to $$c = \frac {-1}{1+\|a\|^2}\left((a\cdot b)a + b + a\times b\right)$$

When $a$ and $b$ are not linearly dependent, then $a = mb$ for some scalar $m$. See if you can figure what is true in this case.

Comment: Arent the two - before b and axb meant to be +?

Comment: Yes. I decided to pull the negatives out, but forgot to change the other two signs.